# Can we use boxicon in SCSS for an Angular project?

Tags: angular, sass

Usually, I use `boxicons` for adding icons. The library is in CSS.

```
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

In an Angular project, I need to use SCSS, I don't understand how I could use `https://boxicons.com`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in head tag of index.html of your angular project

```
<head>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

And then use icons like this

```
<i class='bx bx-user'></i>
```